# UserID or Fix user track in Google Analytics

Tags: html, google-analytics

If I have 100 customers, & each customer can insert in my website after login,

I want to track user id through google analytics who logged-in my website? Please give me best solution?

What code I need to add in my website or How to set tracking code in google analytics?

Comment: You might want to visit the vendor info pages, they offer the best info what is possible. If such a code snippet does not work or you do not understand some specific snippet / API call, would be a good time to come back and update the question. As it stands it may or may not attract people willing to help ;-)

Comment: It's not enough to add some code, you need to understand the process behind it and how to set up your reports to make this useful. Start with the documentation: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123663. The code changes are trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto'); //UA-XXXXX-Y place your GA tracking code instead this
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->

 ga('send', 'event', 'Login', 'User', 'userID#'+userID); // place your  userID
```

Comment: Please guide me how to setup userid google analytics.